# BottomNavigationView into Fragment into ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview

I've a Fragment with a `RecyclerView` and a `BottomNavigationView`.
This fragment will be placed into a `ViewPager` with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Now when I use this fragment into this ViewPager the bottombar is hidden under the NavigationBar and when I scroll up it will displayed.
My question is: How can I lock the bottombar always visible?

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewPager has a height equals of the parent.

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Change it for `wrap_content`

Note: In your case you also need to set the layout_gravity of it to "bottom" since else it would start on 0,0 of a FrameLayout.

Or better, to fit all remaining space, change your FrameLayout to LinearLayout with android:orientation="vertical"

Then add layout_weight="1" to your ViewPager.

Comment: 1. ViewPager is into a CoordinatorLayout if I se it to wrap_content it does not make sense.

or better??

FrameLayout is used as container if you see my xml th ViewPager is into CoordinatorLayout change FrameLayout to LinearLayout does not make changes.

Comment: Why you need the FrameLayout then?

Comment: You don't need Coordinator layout if you want a fixed Bar, you need a layout

Comment: Yes this is true but the coordinator is used for AppBar

Comment: So add it out of the CoordinatorLayout inside a Layout that places it as my suggestion of chaning the Frame for a Linear

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but my problem is that the bottomnavigator is into a fragment place into activity that I've posted